# How to stop the CRON's set using SSH access

Tags: java, php, jobs, cron

How to stop the CRON's set using SSH access. These CRON's are not displayed in my control panel as they are set using SSH access. I do have a ROOT access as its a virtual server.

Please help me.

Regards
Gourav.

Comment: Cronjobs running as another user? You don't have root access?

Comment: Yes, I do have a ROOT access as its a virtual server.

Comment: By the way, I think this belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are at the command prompt, you can use:

```
crontab -l      // list crontab entries
crontab -e      // edit crontab entries
crontab -r      // remove all crontab entries
```

All of the current user of course (can be root).

Answer (score 1):

Try running `crontab -l` in ssh, which shows the list of cron jobs. If this list is different to what you have in your control panel, run `crontab -e` and delete the lines you don't want.

Of course, because it's not your server, there may be other users running cron jobs, which you can't control...